# How can ethers.js using infura as provider?

Tags: ethers.js

How can I use Infura as the provider for ethers.js?
Whether I can use sendtransaction api in ethers.js if I use infura as the provider?

Comment: Please post code that you tried and did not work.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, ethers.js has an [Infura provider](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/api-providers/#InfuraProvider).
2. Since Infura doesn't provide ethereum accounts you have to manage it your side. Ethers.js has wallets that can be used with any of their providers [Wallet and signers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet).

Answer (score 3):

Here's is an example mainnet configuration in `truffle-config.js` using **Infura**:

```
        mainnet: {
        provider: function() {
            return new HDWalletProvider(
                process.env.MNEMONIC,
                `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`
            )
        },
        gas: 2500000,
        gasPrice: 25000000000,
        confirmations: 2,
        network_id: 1
    },
```

If you have `"dotenv": "^8.2.0"` installed, you can add your **Infura** API key in a file called env:

```
INFURA_API_KEY="..."
```

Otherwise you can just enter your full **Infura** key in to the url in `truffle-config.js`.